# Problem with terminal transparency

Tags: 14.04, unity, command-line

I have a problem with the terminal on my Ubuntu netbook. Whenever I open the terminal it is completely transparent without a menubar or anything, and I can't see the text at all. Right clicking on it and messing around with the profiles doesn't do anything, and basically the only thing that the terminal shows is a silhouette. I know it's still there because if I click on the terminal and type in

```
unity -- reset
```

Unity appears to reset, and the terminal is again visible but I lose the ability to alt-tab and my taskbar is gone.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: problem seems to be with Unity not terminal. You may try reinstalling the unity package by purging it completely first by following commands:
sudo apt-get purge remove unity. This will completely remove the unity package. Remember you will lost the gui after you remove it but can reinstall via command line by pressing crtl+alt+F1.

Comment: Did you try to remove the gnome-terminal profiles directory? (then first log out/in before opening the terminal(!!)) (~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal), forcing to recreate the profiles.

Answer (score -1):

You can install [Compiz Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). Open your terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After that open it and go to "Windows management" and check "Application switcher".

About missing taskbar - maybe is because you have disabled unity plugin. You can search for it in Compiz Config and enable it. You can try also this in the terminal:

```
 export DISPLAY=:0
 sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
 setsid unity
```

If this does not work you can reinstall unity:

```
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity
```